# Game Center Achievement Analytics

Tags: ios, analytics, game-center

I've been installing achievements into my iOS game recently using Game Center, and all appears to be fine.

What I'm wondering is is there anyway I can gather analytics on these achievements? I can't see anything explicit in iTunes Connect so I'm looking for something else I imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [flurry analytics](http://www.flurry.com/) you can easily do this. If you are looking for an iTunes Connect or Apple way of doing this there is no feature.

Flurry is 100% free to use and extremely easy to install into your app. It's pretty much drag and drop a few imports and then you're just added one line of code to track specific things.

How I suggest you do this is insert the `[FlurryAPI logEvent:@"EVENT_NAME"]` call in the same statement that you call an achievement in your iOS game.

Currently you can see in my game what the analytics look like:

[image]

Comment: I'll take a gander at this tomorrow when I have some time free to code but this looks incredibly detailed and presented. If it works for what I need I'll come back and market he answer - thank you for the reply.